# Texture painting gone wrong

Tags: texturing, uv, normals, texture-painting

I've been lurking on many tutorials now, still doesn't fix my problem.

I have this level I'd like to paint texture on.

When I do, it gets me crazy-ugly-uncomprehensible results like this.

I tried smoothing it, multiple texture settings adjustments, it keeps messy.

Hours, days I've been crying over this.

Thank you very much for your help.

(a very secondary problem is I just want the normals/ambient occlusion to be painted, without the colour)
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is told in your question that you'd like to paint normals/ambient occlusion without color however painting with normal map texture is shown on your screenshot. So what would you like to paint with ? Is blocky painted result on the 2nd screenshot what you'd like to avoid ?

Comment: It's exactly what I want to avoid :)  thank you                                 yes but the fact it paints the normal maps' colours is disturbing me, I'll check if the colours disappear on rendering.